# Unable to pass environment variables within hotrod-client.properties in OpenShift

Tags: jboss, openshift, infinispan, hot-rod, redhat-datagrid

I have an application that is deployed in Redhat Openshift. The application also uses hotrod client to connect to RedHata Data Grid in Openshift. I have hotrod-client.properties in my application classpath to connect to RDG by specifying the properties required for hotrod.

It looks as follows:

```
infinispan.client.hotrod.server_list=test:443
infinispan.client.hotrod.client_intelligence=BASIC
infinispan.client.hotrod.auth_username=user
infinispan.client.hotrod.auth_password=pass
```

When I give the properties as above everything seems to be working fine.

However when I give them as environment-variables/configmap within openshift environment it is unable to read the values

```
infinispan.client.hotrod.server_list=${URL}
infinispan.client.hotrod.client_intelligence=${AUTH}
infinispan.client.hotrod.auth_username=${USER}
infinispan.client.hotrod.auth_password=${PASS}
```

When I give as below it is unable to fetch the values.
** P.S** : I have other properties files within my application and environment variables seems to work fine there. The issue is only with hotrod-client.properties file.

Attaching links for reference:
[Running data grid on openshift](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_data_grid/8.1/html/running_data_grid_on_openshift/connecting_clients)